# expand grid 100% its parent div, no other scrolls

Tags: css, layout, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

can you help me to fix this layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHdlW.jpg

I'd like the grid will fill totally (hoizontally and vertically) its parent div without show me the outermost scrolbar(the window scollbar)
The only scrollbar that i'd like to see  are the those of the grid

the page has a kendoSplitter in the middle

this is my markup

```
<body>
    <img src="images/logo.png" />
    <h1>Archivio documentale</h1>
     <div id="horizontal" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
            <div id="left-pane">
                <div class="pane-content" style="width:390px;">
                    <!-- LEFT SIDE CONTENT initial fixed width -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main-pane">
                <div class="pane-content">
                     <div id="mainGrid"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Viewports`. There is `vh` (View Height) and `vw` (View Width). `vh` takes the height of the window dinamically, and `vw` takes the width of the window also dinamically.

Therefore, by applying the following:

```
div{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Your grid would always fit 100% no matter what.

Example: http://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/oYKpqK

I hope it helps :)

Comment: which div element do i need to add these attributes to? the  grid's <div> element? its parent? the main container?
do i need add some other tags like <viewport ...something>
i can't use viewport :-(

Comment: You should add it to a div with the class of "single" or "global" which will serve as the "body's" tag. So, it would be <body> -> <div class="global"> -> (all the other content here)